# C++ Dynamically Allocated Array; Size set by quantity of user input; Writing to a file;

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream, ofstream

```
        // lets user input ingredients; but when "n" is inputted it terminates the loop
        string test;
        static int counter = 0;
        string* gredients = new string[counter];
        string newingredients;
        while (test != "no")
        {
            getline(cin,newingredients);
            gredients[counter] = newingredients;
            if (newingredients == "n"){test = "no";}
            counter++;
        }

        // write ingredients to file
        int counter3=1;
        ofstream ob;
        ob.open(recipeName+".txt");
        // counter - 1 is so, because i do not want it to output n into the file
        ob << recipeName << " has "<<  counter-1  << " ingredients." << endl;
        for(int a = 0; a <= counter-1  ; a++)
        {
            ob  << gredients[a] << endl;
        }
        ob.close();
```

When I try to write the array to a file, not everything i've inputted into the array is outputted into the file. In this case i've inputted two things into the array cats then rats. The problem is, my program only outputs cats but not rats. The only possible problem i can think of is that the for loop is not set properly. But I dont think that's the case because the 'counter' in the for loop is clearly set correctly - the file even displays the number of things within the array. So to reiterate, why is it that not everything i've inputted into the array is showing up in the text file.

Txt File Output:
catsandrats has 2 ingredients.
cats

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, this is what you want to do:

```
vector<string> myVector;
string input;

cin >> input;
while (input != "n")
{
    myVector.push_back(input);
    cin >> input;
}

ofstream output;
output.open(recipeName + ".txt");

output << recipeName << " has " << myVector.size() << " ingredients." << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++)
{
    output << myVector[i] << " ";
}

output.close();
```

Array sizes are unchangeable; if you declare an array of size ten, then fiddling with the eleventh element will yield undefined behavior.

In your program, you initially create an array of size zero (what is that, in the first place?) and then try to alter data beyond its bounds—undefined behavior right there.

However, programmers have come up with two common solutions to this problem: either create a sufficiently large array (large enough to guarantee not going out of bounds anytime soon) and keep a count of its items, or implement a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).

In a nutshell, a linked list is an array whose size can be dynamically altered, and a `std::vector` exposes behavior similar to a linked list's.

Comment: I'm not all too familiar with vectors. Could you explain in layman's terms what a vector is? What you've written is probably right on point, but I just want to understand why is it better to use vectors than what I did?

Answer (score 1):

```
   static int counter = 0;
   string* gredients = new string[counter];
```

You are allocating an array of 0 strings and then accessing elements of that array. That would be undefined behaviour.

Comment: Well the idea was that the amount of user inputted ingredients would define the size of the array. Does that not work? Should i code it differently?